# Angular custom filter returning error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I build a custom filter for my expression. And it works somehow. anyway i am keep getting an error which i cannot figure out why?
The error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null"

This is my filter:

```
LeadApp.filter("q_Filter", function () {
    return function (input, splitChar, index) {
        if (index === 1) {
            q_a = input.split(splitChar);
            return q_a[1];
        }
        else {
            q_a = input.split(splitChar);
            return q_a[0];
        }
    };
});
```

Here is the view:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="select in lead_selection" ng-show="select.length && $index > 4">
    <td>
       <i class="fa fa-circle-thin"></i>
       <strong>{{ select | q_Filter:' | ':0 | uppercase }}</strong> <br />
       <p class="p-l-1">{{ select | q_Filter:' | ':1 }}</p>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check `input` is `null` or not before `split` input value.

this error shown because your `input` was `null` or `empty`

```
LeadApp.filter("q_Filter", function () {
    return function (input, splitChar, index) {

        if(!input) { 
           return '';
        }

        if (index === 1) {
            q_a = input.split(splitChar);
            return q_a[1];
        }
        else {
            q_a = input.split(splitChar);
            return q_a[0];
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just have a check on input that input must have some value before calling

```
input.split(splitChar)
```

and one more thing make sure that input contains splitChar as well